# addPropertyMapping method of RKObjectMapping work only for one property mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

When i use `addPropertyMapping` method of `RKObjectMapping` for two times it will not work fine. I mean, we can add a `RKRelationshipMappping` by `addPropertyMapping`. It will work fine for relationshipMapping that you firstly added only. Why? is there any alternative to set more than one properyMapping?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add as many mappings as you want. Internally, the mappings are stored in an array so that isn't a limit. Something else is wrong.

Internally, `addPropertyMappingsFromArray:` and `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:` both call `addPropertyMapping`.

If you have disabled assertions then an error could be getting thrown and you're not seeing it...

Comment: but, the first added mapping works fine. When i interchange mappings, the other (added first) mapping works fine then. So here problem is not considering the second added relation mapping. then i tested [membMapping addPropertyMappingsFromArray:@[membStatusRelation,userRelation]]; here also 'membStatusRelation' only be considered.

Comment: Hmm. Need to debug the addition to the array, just step into the call in the debugger. Also, turn on trace logging during the mapping and check the log details: `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: I did not disable Assertions, but still i wont get any error and in mapping only first one is considered as i told you earlier.

Comment: So the trace log doesn't mention the second mapping name at all? Very strange as internally all methods of adding mappings are done in the same way and add the mappings into the same array...

Comment: No. log doesn't mention the second mapping name any where, i checked well.

Comment: I'd look at debugging the call, trace through that it adds the mapping to the array. Then later when the array is used to map the incoming data, is the mapping still there. I don't know a reason why it's doing what you observe.